# How can I use Sidekiq to render large PDFs as a background process to avoid Heroku's 30 second timeout for HTTP requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq, wicked-pdf

I'm no expert, but my hours of googling and stack overflowing haven't given me an answer to my problem, so I decided to make my own question.

I'm using Ruby on Rails 5 which I'm tinkering with using the Cloud9 IDE on AWS. The app is deployed using Heroku which has a 30 second timeout for HTTP requests. I need to generate a PDF from an html.erb file that has a lot of logic and queries in it, so it usually takes around 100 seconds to complete, and, since it happens in the controller, it is considered an HTTP request and is required to either take less than 30 seconds or be completed as a background process. If you know of another way to get around the Heroku 30 second HTTP request timeout, PLEASE let me know.

I asked about this in another post and got the feedback to try using something like Sidekiq with rails to process the massive process instead of attempting it with an HTTP request. The idea here was to put it in a background request and let it do its thing for the full 100+ seconds, then return the PDF to the end user somehow (like having it download automatically for example). I decided to go for it, and got my code working to the point where I had the Redis server (required for Sidekiq), the Sidekiq server, and the usual rails server all running in unison to allow me to load and render the PDF from the Sidekiq worker instead of the controller.

My problem is that the 'render' method is not available in workers! I attempted to access it directly from the source by using 
`av = ActionView::Base.new()`
 and then 
`av.render #pdf code here`

but got the following error in my Sidekiq console:

"WARN: NameError: uninitialized constant PDFWorker::ActionView"

The code in my controller:

```
# /app/controllers/recentgrad_controller.rb 
require 'sidekiq'
require "redis"
class RecentgradController < ApplicationController
  def report
    # things that prepare the name of the pdf, etc. go here

    PDFWorker.perform_async(pdf_name, pdf_year)
    redirect_to emphs_path
  end
end
```

The code in my worker:

```
# /app/workers/pdf_worker.rb
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  # config.redis = { db: 1 }
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://172.31.6.51:6379/0' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  # config.redis = { db: 1 }
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://172.31.6.51:6379/0' }
end  

class PDFWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: false
  def perform(pdf_name, pdf_year)
    # create an instance of ActionView, so we can use the render method outside of a controller
    av = ActionView::Base.new() # THIS is where the error comes from
    av.view_paths = ActionController::Base.view_paths
    av.class_eval do
      include ActionController::UrlWriter
      include ApplicationHelper
    end

    av.render pdf: "mypdf", 
      disposition: 'attachment',
      page_height: 1300,
         encoding: 'utf8',
        page_size:   'A4',
           footer: {html: {template: 'recent_grad/footer.html.erb'}, spacing: 0 },
           margin:  {   top:    10,                     # default 10 (mm)
                        bottom: 20,
                        left:   10,
                        right:  10 },
         template: "recent_grad/report.html.erb",
           locals: {start: @start, survey: @survey, years: @years, college: @college, department: @department, program: @program, emphasis: @emphasis, questions: @questions}
  end
end
```

The error I get when I run the part of my program that generates a PDF:

`WARN: NameError: uninitialized constant PDFWorker::ActionView`

Comment: `av = ::ActionView::Base.new()` Use it with double colon so it does not search the class in the `PDFWorker` namespace.

Comment: @DennyMueller Thanks for the reply! I made the change, reset my sidekiq server to make sure the change took affect, and am still getting this: 

2019-05-23T15:55:45.665Z 5244 TID-5vcdw WARN: NameError: uninitialized constant ActionView

2019-05-23T15:55:45.665Z 5244 TID-5vcdw WARN: /home/ec2-user/environment/gradSurvey/app/workers/pdf_worker.rb:16:in `perform'

Where like 16 in pdf_worker.rb is 

av = ::ActionView::Base.new()

Any idea why it would still be saying that?

Comment: @DennyMueller any idea why the double colon isn't working? I attempted it on ```::ApplicationController``` as well with no luck.

Comment: No idea, have you tried to requiring the missing rails part? `require 'action_view'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be much easier to use a job instead of a worker because jobs allow you to use the render function inherited from the `ApplicationController`

The real winner here is @unixmonkey who is the creator of wicked pdf for rails, and he set up a working app for me. You can see the question here: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/835

And the commit that really changed the way it worked can be viewed here: 
https://github.com/unixmonkey/generate_pdf_async_example/commit/85e8dcd98fe6580a8692842fcc5316b931ce4eea

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

A Sidekiq job is not a controller action, it has no implicit state like parameters, query string, request headers, cookies, etc.

You might find that is simpler to render the template directly.  I'm not sure what you are using to convert the HTML output into PDF, I use `wkhtmltopdf` in my system.  Here's how I render a simple HTML ERB template and convert it to a PDF so I can email it to a customer.

```rb
    require 'erb'

    localvar = "this is visible to the template"
    content = ERB.new(File.read("some_template.html.erb")).result(binding)

    tmpf = Tempfile.new(['sometemplate', '.html'])
    tmpf.write(content)
    tmpf.close

    result = `wkhtmltopdf #{tmpf.path} #{tmpf.path}.pdf 2>&1`
    raise result if $?.exitstatus != 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MikePerham I did see that it's simpler to render the template directly, but it takes too long. The html.erb file that I am using queries the db multiple times to get the correct information on the page, so it takes just the render function about 105 seconds to complete. I am also using wicked pdf, but the Heroku HTTP request 30 second timeout is preventing me from just rendering it as is. Do you know how I can get around that? Or make it render faster? Is it possible to finish all of the queries for the HTML somewhere else and just render the pdf from the completed html?